# How to calculate the projected usage and rates information fetched from the AWS subscription?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am trying to calculate the projected usage and rates information fetched from the AWS subscription, I would like a slightly more targeted answer.

Comment: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html ?

Comment: Please provide more information about what data you have and what you are trying to accomplish.